# RESTHeart instance stops without any error

Tags: restheart

I am running 4 different RESTHeart demon instances on a single server, it is connecting to different Mongo Databases.
I have given different ports for these 4 instances and have different property files.

RESTHeart server stops suddenly, I do not see any error in logs I run it debug mode. I am not sure what is the cause, restarting it works fine for another few days or a day.

Answer (score 1):

As we have several RESTHeart instances running for months in a row, the described behaviour sounds unusual and could depend on a set of causes. We need to know much more about the context before we can make a hypothesis.

For example, we need to know:

- Which version of RESTHeart
- If it's dockerized or not
- If not in which operating system is running
- How do you run it (e.g. are you using something such as upstart or systemd to start it and keep it running in the background?)
- What is the estimated load of the process (situations where a massive load could potentially cause an OOM?)
- What are the heap memory parameters are you using for the Java process and what is the total memory of the host server

At the end of the day, RESTHeart is a plain Java application, so this looks like an operating system issue: something is sending the process a kill signal? Due to external load, does the Java process go abruptly in "out of memory" without even having a chance to log anything?

Please provide more context.